# Python pickle instance variables

Tags: python, pickle

I am doing some calculations on an instance variable, and after that is done I want to pickle the class instance, such that I don't have to do the calculations again. Here an example:

```
import cPickle as pickle

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = None
    def compute(self, x):
        print 'calculating c...'
        self.c = x * 2

test = Test(10, 'hello')
test.compute(6)

# I have computed c and I want to store it, so I don't have to recompute it again:

pickle.dump(test, open('test_file.pkl', 'wb'))
```

After `test.compute(6)` I can check to see what `test.__dict__` is:

```
>>> test.__dict__
{'a': 10, 'c': 12, 'b': 'hello'}
```

I thought that is what going to get pickled; however,

When I go to load the class instance:

```
import cPickle as pickle

from pickle_class_object import Test

t2 = pickle.load(open('test_file.pkl', 'rb'))
```

I see this in the shell:

```
calculating c...
```

Which means that I did not pickle `c` and I am computing it over again.

Is there a way to pickle `test` how I want to? So I don't have to compute `c` over again. I see that I could just pickle `test.__dict__`, but I am wondering if there is a better solutions. Also, my understanding about what is going on here is weak, so any comment about what is going would be great. I've read about `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`, but I don't see how to apply them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickling works as you expect it to work.  The problem here is when you run the new script, you import the module that contains the class `Test`.  That entire module is run including the bit where you create `test`.

The typical way to handle this sort of thing would be to protect the stuff in a `if __name__ == "__main__:` block.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = None
    def compute(self, x):
        print 'calculating c...'
        self.c = x * 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import cPickle as pickle

    test = Test(10, 'hello')
    test.compute(6)

    # I have computed c and I want to store it, so I don't have to recompute it again:

    pickle.dump(test, open('test_file.pkl', 'wb'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are importing the `pickle_class_object` module again, and Python runs *all* code in that module.

Your top-level module code includes a call to `.compute()`, that is what is being called.

You may want to move the code that creates the pickle *out* of the module, or move it to a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guarded section:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test(10, 'hello')
    test.compute(6)

    pickle.dump(test, open('test_file.pkl', 'wb'))
```

Only when running a python file as the main script is `__name__` set to `__main__`; when imported as a module `__name__` is set to the module name instead and the `if` branch will not run.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't what's happening.  You import a python module that has code in it at the top level, which executes when you import the module.  You can see that your code works as you intended:

```
import cPickle as pickle

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = None
    def compute(self, x):
        print 'calculating c...'
        self.c = x * 2

test = Test(10, 'hello')
test.compute(6)

pickle.dump(test, open('test_file.pkl', 'wb'))

t2 = pickle.load(open('test_file.pkl', 'rb'))
print t2.c


--output:--
calculating c...
12
```

If your code worked as you describe, then you would see "calculating c..." twice.